# Strongly Typed Data Context Must Declare a Body Error

Tags: c#, .net, datacontext, sqlconnection

Receiving this error:

```
Error   4   'ZoneUpdates.Models.PgeDataContext.PgeDataContext(string, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial    C:\Code\ZoneUpdates\ZoneUpdates\Models\PgeDataContext.cs    18  16  ZoneUpdates
Error   6   'ZoneUpdates.Models.ZoneObject.SendPropertyChanged(string)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial   C:\Code\ZoneUpdates\ZoneUpdates\Models\PgeDataContext.cs    42  32  ZoneUpdates
```

Basically 13 errors between these four classes (two shown following).

I'm using 4.0 and I've basically copy and pasted this code from another project where it works as expected. I've tried changing the classes to partial, to no avail. Any pointers is appreciated.

```
[Database(Name = "Pge_Dev")]
public class PgeDataContext : DataContext
{
    public PgeDataContext(IDbConnection connection);
    public PgeDataContext(string dsn);
    public PgeDataContext(
              IDbConnection connection, 
              System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource);
    public PgeDataContext(
              string connection, 
              System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource);

    public Table<ZoneObject> ZoneObject { get; set; }
    public Table<ZoneObjType> ZoneObjType { get; set; }
    public Table<ZoneTypeBridge> ZoneTypeBridge { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "dbo.ZoneObject")]
public class ZoneObject : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ZoneObject();

    [Column(Storage = "ID", DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Storage = "Name", DbType = "nvarchar(30)")]
    public int Name { get; set; }
    [Column(Storage = "Value", DbType = "bigint")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    [Column(Storage = "CancurrencyID", DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
    public int ConcurrencyID { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName);
    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Examples of errors**

Constructors without body

```
public PgeDataContext(IDbConnection connection);
```

=> you have to declare a body

```
public PgeDataContext(IDbConnection connection){ /*blibli*/ }
```

Methods without body

`protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName);`

=> You have to declare a body for non abstract, extern or partial methods, as stated in your error message

`protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
/*blabla*/
}`

Comment: This is obviously the right answer, I was just looking for if there was an something else possible for me to do, because as mentioned, this was taken from another project where this worked. Possibly there was more do it, but I drilled down as much as I could and this seemed to be all that was used.

Comment: @mgaughan: that code as written is invalid C# and would never have worked.  However, is it possible that the code was copied from an `abstract` class?  It would be closer to valid in that case.

Comment: @DanPuzey that's really what I was looking to learn here. I figured it was some kind of inheritance or abstraction, but I couldn't find the exact statement making that clear. Thanks.